# Using vysor for remote adb debugging

Tags: adb, remote-access

Hi I have a computer X connected to Android phone A at my home via USB, I would like to give a remote computer Y outside my home network ability to view the phone and do remote debugging(via adb). I thought Vysor Enterprise was able to do this. But Although I can view and control `A` on `Y` using the Vysor App I am unable to see anything on adb devices on `Y`. Ultimately I want to install apps from `Y` onto it in Android Studio. Both the computers are Macbooks with Monterey and the Android phone has Android 11 or later.

I have raised this question on github https://github.com/koush/vysor.io/issues/1079 but I think the Vysor's author's response was not clear. Has someone faced and solved this issue? Any alternatives to Vysor?

Comment: adb over tcpip only works if Y and A connected to same wifi

Comment: Vysor only allows you to see the remote screen and forward mouse & keyboard commands to the remote machine. If you want to forward adb connection to a remote machine you have to set-up that separately. I don't know if Vysor supports TCP forwarding, if yes you can use that. If not you need a second channel like SSH for TCP forwarding. Search the net for "adb forward remote machine 5037" and you end up on a page like this: https://www.paincker.com/adb-remote/